# Kotlin error: Evaluation stopped while it's taking too long️

Tags: kotlin, async-await, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

I'm new to Kotlin and reading through docs and examples of how to use coroutines and async. I have the following code that I'm running in the [Kotlin playground](https://play.kotlinlang.org/) but not sure why I'm getting the error `Evaluation stopped while it's taking too long️.`

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import kotlin.system.measureTimeMillis

val executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10).asCoroutineDispatcher()

suspend fun fooAsyncS(): Int = fooAsync("").await()

fun fooAsync(id: String): Deferred<Int> = GlobalScope.async(executor) {
    delay(1000)
    1
}

fun main() = runBlocking {
    val timeElapsed = measureTimeMillis {
        fooAsyncS()
    }

    println("$timeElapsed")
    println("Hello")
}
```

The following code below works but I'm not sure why the above doesn't. Any thoughts?

```
suspend fun example(): String {
    println("computing result")
    delay(5000)
    return "data"
}

fun main() = runBlocking {
    val timeElapsed = measureTimeMillis {
        launch {
            example()
        }
    }

    println("$timeElapsed")
    println("Hello")
}
```

Comment: Seems to be specific to using executors on Kotlin Playground. Running this in IntelliJ or using a different Dispatcher on the Playground both work.